# Load jQuery only on home page

Tags: css

I am working in a premium wordpress theme... It is a complex wordpress theme with lots of admin features so i feel very difficult to edit... Now i need to move a sidebar upwards only in homepage... i use this code...

```
.classname{
  position:relative;
  top:-300;
}
```

But the code above is moving the sidebar on all pages... since the site is complex i don't know where to add specific class name for sidebar in homepage... So i decided to use jQuery to find whether the page is home page or not... if it is homepage then i move the sidebar upwards, else not...

Please say me how to find whether the page is homepage or not using jQuery...

Comment: Added WordPress tags. Removed jQuery tag.

Comment: and why/how do you think jQuery should figure out whether it's the startpage or not? you have php as your backend - do your magic within this framework!

Comment: No need for jQuery here

Answer (score 3):

WordPress adds a series of classes to the body tag (assuming your theme-designer used [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)) depending on which page you're currently viewing. On the homepage, WordPress adds the `home` class. You could use this to target *only* the sidebar viewed on the homepage:

```
body.home .classname {
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
}
```